# Habilitar desabilitar Múltiplos Campos Especificos

Tags: javascript

Ola A todos Como não tenho nenhuma experiencia com javascript gostaria de uma ajuda
de como habilitar o desabilitar alguns campos expecificos.

Nesse Script a baixo e é exatamente o que eu preciso só que ao colocar ele no codigo
ele desabilita campos que não precisam estar desabilitado.
Gostaria de saber como esse código pode ser alterado para só para alguns campos que contenho exemplo.. um id=x

```
 <script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
 $(window).load(function(){
 $(document).ready(function() {
 $("#enable").click(function (){
            // habilita o campo 
    $("input").prop("disabled", false);
    $("select").prop("disabled", false);

 });

 $("#disable").click(function (){
            // desabilita o campo 
    $("input").prop("disabled", true);
    $("select").prop("disabled", true);
});
});
});//]]>  
</script>
<button href="#" id="enable" >Habilita Campos</button>
<button href="#" id="disable" >Desabilita Campos</button>

<input type="text" id="campo" name="campo1" disabled/> <br/>
<input type="text" id="campo" name="campo2" disabled/> <br/>
<input type="text"            name="campo3" disabled/> <!--exemplo Não fazer nada -->
```

Comment: Não podes ter elementos diferentes com o mesmo ID. É sempre o mesmo input que queres desabilitar?

Comment: Vamos diz que tenho 10 inputs, mais só quero Habilitar/desabilitar 4

Comment: O que eu quero saber é como os queres escolher, para poder responder.

Comment: Sim eu tenho que escolher mais não sei por onde pode fazer essa escolha , ou se poderia ser assim, todos que tivere id="1", id="2", id="3"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para desabilitar um input tens de usar `.prop("disabled", true);` numa coleção de elementos.

Para criares uma coleção (que pode ter 1 ou mais elementos) usa-se o `$('regras de CSS')`.

Para escolheres todos os inputs podes fazer como já tens: `$('input')`.
Para escolheres pelo nome: `$('input[name="campo2"]')`.
Para escolheres multiplos: `$('input[name="campo2"], input[id="campo1"]')`.

#### Exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/vw4qns0x/

O que está a faltar na tua pergunta é como sabes quel é o input que queres desabilitar, mas espero que os exemplo ajudem.